# Show loading indicator /spinner when the page data isn't fully loaded from Firebase - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In my Flutter app, I am using ModalProgressHUD to show a spinner when I click on save buttons in my form screens and it stops spinner once data successfully writes to Firebase.

I have this screen that uses Listview.builder to display a list of all my expenses and I want to automatically show spinner as soon as the page displays, and to stop spinner once all the data from Firebase fully loads.

I need assistance in doing this. I've pasted excerpt of my code as shown below. Thanks in advance.

```
//class wide declaration
bool showSpinner = true;



Widget build(BuildContext context) {

ExpenseNotifier expenseNotifier = Provider.of<ExpenseNotifier>(context);


Future<void> _resfreshList() async {
  expenseNotifier.getExpenses(expenseNotifier);
  var expenseList = ExpenseNotifier.getExpenses(expenseNotifier);
  if (expenseList != null) {
    setState(() {
      showSpinner = false;
    });
}

    return Scaffold(
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
            inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _resfreshList,
              child: Consumer<ExpenseNotifier>(
                builder: (context, expense, child) {
                  return expense == null
                      ? Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            PaddingClass(bodyImage: 'images/empty.png'),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'You don\'t have any expenses',
                              style: kLabelTextStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      : ListView.separated(
                          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                            var myExpense = expense.expenseList[index];
                            return Card(
                              elevation: 8.0,
                              color: Colors.white70,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  RegularExpenseTextPadding(
                                    regText:
                                        '${_formattedDate(myExpense.updatedAt)}',
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: kThemeStyleBorderHighlightColour),
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 5,
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(
                                                '${myExpense.amount}',
                                                style: kRegularTextStyle,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 20.0,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                myExpense.description,
                                                style: kRegularTextStyle,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 1,
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              expenseNotifier.currentExpense =
                                                  expenseNotifier
                                                      .expenseList[index];
                                              Navigator.of(context).push(
                                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                                                      (BuildContext context) {
                                                return ExpenseDetailsScreen();
                                              }));
                                            },
                                            child: Icon(
                                              FontAwesomeIcons.caretDown,
                                              color: kThemeIconColour,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: expenseNotifier.expenseList.length,
                        );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example from my app:

```
bool _isLoading = false; <- default false
  bool _isInit = true; <- to mae it only load once


@override
  void initState() {

if (_isInit) {
     // activating spinner
      _isLoading = true;

      // your function here <------

    _isInit = false;
    super.initState();
  }
```

Initstate gets called before the user can see any kind of thin in your app, so this is the perfect place to make your firebase data load. with this logic from above the loading spinner shows as long you are receiving the data. And your body looks like the following then:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return _isLoading <- is loading condition true? shows spinner
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) <- loading spinner
    // else shows your content of the app
    : SafeArea(
        child: Container()
            ....
```

Comment: Hey Marcel, I tried emulating your suggested sample above. I set the default value of isLoading to true, because I want the spinner to show immediately the page loads and set it to false when data is successfully read from db. But the spinner doesn't stop even after the page is fully loaded. I've edited my question to include the updates I made. To find changes, check the showSpinner declaration, the inAsyncCall, the _resfreshList function.

Comment: @hermie_brown Please check my code I changed it, as you responded to my code I just noticed that I took the wrong part from my file. Now it is correct, take this for your construct it should work now. You gonna load it with initstate and after loading complete display the app content. Do it like in my example keeping the isLoading to false so you dont get in trouble with something